# Office 365 Powerpoint for Mac cannot input Chinese

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, osx-yosemite

[Powerpoint fails to show word candidate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaYNy.png)The word candidate window fail to appear after inputing the SuCheng ()codes. Word, Excel have no problem. Only powerpoint.

Any fix?

Thank you,
Eric

[Word can](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCHbW.png)

Comment: Powerpoint for Windows 10 no issue.

Comment: Have you added Chinese as a keyboard language and enabled it?  I'm not a regular Mac user but as I recall I had to go to System Preferences | Keyboards or similar to enable alternate languages (in my case, Japanese) and then switch to that language via the icon on the menu bar.